# UITableView and TabbarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview, tabbar

I am working on iphone news application, I want to display tableview which are having single section and ten rows just after splash image and after clicking any row want to display TabBar which have five to six tabBar items. Please anybody help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have two `viewControllers` (**first**)one for `tableView` and another (**second**)`viewcontroller` where you will display `tabbarController`.

Now in in **second** `viewControlers` xib you drag n drop `UITabBarCotroller` from library using IB.
In app Delegate create a reference for this `viewController` and also make it as property so that you can access it. also initialize it in `didFinishLaunching` method of `appDelegate`.

and in **first** viewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath(delegate method of UITableView) 
access **second** `viewController` from `appDelegate`. and push(if your **first** `viewcontroller` is `navigation` based) or present it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

refer this site:
http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/datapicker.html

or

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/tabbarcontroller-with-navigationcontroller-and-tableview-in-iphone/

it may helps you..